Flutter leading property only locates center
I'm making my project with flutter, and used ListTile Widget, and set icons in ListTile's leading.
but It only locates in center.. I used Align, Center, Container decoration and so on.

here's the code
ListTile(
  horizontalTitleGap: 10,
  leading: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    child: CircleAvatar(child: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.dog, size:28, color: Colors.white), backgroundColor: Color(0xffB8CCA3)),
  ),
  title: Text(" ${messages[index].nickname}", textAlign: TextAlign.left, style: TextStyle(fontSize:14)),
  subtitle: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: Container(
        margin : const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:5),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 5, 15, 5),
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth:320
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xffe9ecef),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        child: Text(messages[index].message, textAlign: TextAlign.left, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17))
    ),
  )
);

I want to make my Icon locates next to nickname like image


leading will display on topLeft by the default, why do you use Align?

I used it to control the chat box size, if don't use Align, then the chatbox width is fixed

set the following property:
titleAlignment: ListTileTitleAlignment.top

title alignment property : Defines how ListTile.leading and ListTile.trailing are vertically aligned relative to the ListTile's titles (ListTile.title and ListTile.subtitle).
for more info here
